# In Django, how do you reference your project urls.py URLs?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am making a django project with multiple apps inside of it. My directory structure is something like this:

```
DjangoProject
    project_dir
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    app1
        urls.py
        ...
    app2
        urls.py
        ...
```

I understand how to access urls in my templates that are part of apps with `{% url 'app1:url1' %}` but that is because in my app urls.py files I can do something like this:

```
app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view1, name='home'),
]
```

The project urls.py file seems to be different than app urls though. You cant give the project urls.py file an `app_name` so how is one supposed to reference project urls from inside a template? I have been just relying on relative links like this: `<a href="/global_url"></a>` but if I ever want to change the path of /global_url I have to go and update all my hard coded template urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a moron. So when you give a url a name in the project urls.py file, when you want to reference it in a template, you just omitt the `app:` portion. So something like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('global_url/', global_views.global_view1, name='global1')
]
```

is accessible in your template like this: `{% url 'global1' %}`